# ASP.NET correct type mapping when method contains dictionary with object as value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

My controllers method:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Manage(GeneratorSchema schema)
```

GeneratorSchema:

```
public class GeneratorSchema
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public GeneratorTypes Type { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> Payload { get; set; }
}
```

Example data send through form POST:

```
<input name="Id" value="*ValidGuid*" />
<input name="Type" value="*ValidEnum*" />
<input name="Payload[Name]" value="Kevin" />
<input name="Payload[Age]" value="22" />
<input name="Payload[Balance]" value="0,55" />
```

When this form is send, controller correctly map this as GeneratorSchema object, but when it comes to dictionary I'm receiving correct keys but values to those keys are an array of strings with only one string inside which is the value from the form. I'm assuming it's becouse the value of dictionary is set as an `object` type.

How to resolve the dictionary data so the value will have correct type without array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By now I've developed a very basic answer.

```
        foreach(var key in schema.Payload.Keys.ToList())
        {
            if(schema.Payload[key].GetType().IsArray)
            {
                string[] value = schema.Payload[key] as string[];
                schema.Payload[key] = value[0];

                double dValue;
                if (double.TryParse((string)schema.Payload[key], out dValue))
                    schema.Payload[key] = dValue;
            }
        }
```